# Drupal 8.4 version update brake webform structure

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-webform

I have updated Drupal to version 8.4, but the update broke the webform structure.

`webform.element.buttons.js` not available in new version of webform module?

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: webform.element.buttons.js not available in new version of webform module?

Answer (score 1):

8.4 included a new version of jQueryUI and webform.element.buttons.buttons.js had to be split into two files to support 8.3< and 8.4+.

Below are the two new files.

- webform.element.buttons.buttonset.js (8.3<)
- webform.element.buttons.checkboxradio.js (8.4+)